# Rails 4 Two Forms, Separate Models On One Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models for communication, Post and Reply. For some reason I can't figure out, the @reply form is unresponsive. Submit does not work, and the file upload field does not work, but only on the @reply form, the @prosect and @post forms work perfectly.

```
<h1><strong><%= @group.name %></strong></h1>
<p><em><%= @group.description %></em><p>
<p>Operated by: <% @owner = User.find(@group.owner_id) %><%= @owner.name %></p>
<% if current_user.group_id == nil %>
  <%= form_for(@prospect) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :group_id, value: @group.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Join Group", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% if current_user.group_id == @group.id %>
  <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :group_id, value: @group.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-11">
          <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "What ails you?" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addpic(0);">Add a pic</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group hidden col-xs-12" id="picture0">
      <%= f.file_field :image, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% @group.posts.each do |p| %>
    <div class="post">
      <div class="post-meta">
        <%= p.user.name %> <em><%= p.created_at.strftime('%a, %b %e, %Y %r') %></em>
      </div>
      <%= p.content %>
      <% if p.image %>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= p.image %>" class="img-responsive"/>
      <% end %>
      <% p.replies.each do |r| %>
        <%= r.user.name %><br/><%= r.content %>
        <% if r.image %>
          <img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= r.image %>" class="img-responsive"/>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <a class="reply">Reply</a>
      <div class="reply hidden">
        <%= form_for(@reply) do |ff| %>
          <%= ff.hidden_field :post_id, value: p.id %>
          <%= ff.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-11">
                <%= ff.text_area :content, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Write a reply..." %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addpic(<%= p.id %>);">Add a pic</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group hidden col-xs-12" id="picture<%= p.id %>">
            <%= ff.file_field :image, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12 actions">
            <%= ff.submit %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<script>
  var addpic = function(id) {
    var el = '#picture' + id;
    $(el).removeClass('hidden');
  }

  $('.reply').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().removeClass('hidden');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How does @reply fails? Does it say anything in your log? Did you check if there's any JS code failure that may be preventing it from submitting?

Comment: no JS to make it fail and the console doesn't show anything, there's the prevent default on the a tag, but that shouldn't affect the form.

Comment: and nothing goes to the server log because the form isn't getting submitted

Comment: @OscarValdezEsquea it shouldn't have, but it did! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I didn't think the JS would've caused that but you made me look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, JS was preventing the default for all clicks inside a .reply div. Had reply used in the wrapper for the reply form, so it was preventing the default. Got it working now by changing the class of the reply link to 'addreply' and the js listener to 'addreply' as well.